# Есть ли алгоритм построения 3D диаграммы Вороного со сложностью o(n log n )?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ли какой-нибудь алгоритм построения 3д диаграммы Вороного со сложностью o(n log n ) ?

Буду рад ссылке на такой алгоритм или хотя бы подтверждению того факта, что алгоритм с такой сложностью в принципе существует.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-854j-advanced-algorithms-fall-2008/lecture-notes/lec23.pdf

Comment: спасибо, но тут приведены два простейших 2д-алгоритма (на 3д не обобщаемых), а меня интересует именно 3д случай...

Comment: Вам нужно точное решение или приближённое? Насколько это важно? Вы умеете строить диаграмму вороного хотя бы за сколько-нибудь?

Comment: решение нужно точное (а что вы кстати называете приближенным в данном случае?) строить умею за n^2,  и в хороших случаях  за n log n....

Comment: [*In fact, computing a Voronoi diagram on n points in R^d can be done in time O(n log n+n^⌈d/2⌉)*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/954336/14325)

Comment: спасибо, очень интересная оценка..

Comment: Я предлагаю нагенерить много примеров. На них построить регрессию. А потом эту регрессию использовать как приближённое решение. Понятно, что мы будем получать примерное решение. Но оно будет близко к точному.

Comment: Для 3D случая у вас два варианта 1) Делаем 2D-проэкцию ручками 2)Используя 3D ускоритель (opengl, DirectX) отрисовуем 3D (x,y,z) точками или линиями, и берём любой готовый кусок кода с "камерой", который позволяет "крутить" и рассматривать изображение с разных сторон.